# Set field after expire (MongoDB)

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, time

I'l have a small structure of DataBase :

```
export const ApplicationSchema = new Schema({
  ownerId: String,
  ownerName: String,
  region: String,
  fromAddress: String,
  phone: String,
  cameAddress: String,
  status: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['new', 'booked', 'completed'],
    default: 'new'
  },
})
```

I need to change 'Status', after 24 hours, Status should be equal to 'booked', how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB has a tool called scheduled triggers, which would allow you to do that:
https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/triggers/scheduled-triggers/

However it would be a complicated and heavy solution for your problem. You could do something with a 'createdAt' field and having a virtual field for you current status:

```
export const ApplicationSchema = new Schema({
  ownerId: String,
  ownerName: String,
  region: String,
  fromAddress: String,
  phone: String,
  cameAddress: String,
  createdAt: Date,
  status: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['new', 'booked', 'completed'],
    default: 'new'
  },
  toJSON: { virtuals: true }
})

ApplicationSchema.virtual('status.current')
  .get(function () {
    // subtracting and checking if it's been a day in milliseconds
    if ((Date.now() - +new Date(this.createdAt)) >= 86400000) {
      return 'completed'
    }

    return this.status
  })
```

You would have to check your status using status.current, instead of status.
Check here (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/virtuals.html) to learn more about virtua fields.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with MongoDB alone.
In my projects I am using this npm package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron

This lets you run tasks periodically. Like a Cron job on Linux systems but this package does not depend on Linux Cron.